# PineScript: How to Plot a label at 20th candle that is above SMA200

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need help for my code below. I would like to plot a "Buy Label" at the 20th candle above SMA200, but I don't know how to write the code correctly. Thanks for any help. :)
`//@version=5
indicator("20th Candlestick Above SMA200", overlay=true)

MA_long = ta.sma(close,200)
var barsAboveMA = 0 // when var is used, the value is not reset to 0 at the start of every bar
if close > MA_long
barsAboveMA := barsAboveMA + 1
else
barsAboveMA := 0

plotshape(barsAboveMA ? low  : na, style=shape.cross, color=color.green, location=location.bottom, size=size.normal)`

I tried write the code but it is not what I want the code to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, here's a working version.

```
//@version=5
indicator("20th Candle", overlay = true)

ma200 = ta.sma(close, 200)
var startCounter = false
var counter = 0

cross = ta.crossover(close,ma200)

startCounter := cross ? true : startCounter
counter := startCounter ? counter + 1 : counter

if close < ma200
    startCounter := false
    counter := 0

plotshape(counter == 21 ? 1 : 0, 'Buy Label', shape.cross, location.belowbar, color.green, size = size.normal, text = 'BUY', textcolor = color.green)
plotchar(counter, 'Counter', ' ', display = display.data_window)
```